# How to limit the amount of space Framelayout takes on screen?

Tags: android

I have created a fragment which displays a bunch of different text. Each time the activity is loaded the text is different. I load this fragment in main activity using a framelayout. At the bottom of my main screen I have created a buttons panel with three buttons with each performing a different action such as play and next item. The problem is that some times when the text data is big and the framelayout expands to the bottom of the screen. How can I limit Framelayout to remain above buttons panel?

In the fragment layout I have multiple TextViews nested in a ScrollView.

**fragment.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragments.TextsFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/english_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="English Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/orignal_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="Original Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/translatied_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="Translated Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

        </LinearLayout>





        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/opening_braces"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/colon"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/line_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                tools:text="42"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/closing_braces"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/word"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            tools:text="Word"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/english_translation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            tools:text="English Translation"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>


    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/play_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_play_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/play"
            android:onClick="onClickPlayButton"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:text="Random"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/play_button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/play_button"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_share_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/share"
            android:onClick="onClickShareButton"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textView3" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_next_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/next"
            android:onClick="onClickNextButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/share_button"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to keep framelayout just above the buttons panel at bottom instead of expanding to bottom of screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I limit Framelayout to remain above buttons panel?

You can tell the surrounding `RelativeLayout` to make sure the `FrameLayout` stays above the buttons panel by using the attribute `android:layout_above` for the `FrameLayout`

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"/>
```

See the [documentation for RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative) to find out more about layout attributes